# Collecting hash with conditions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Model: project.rb

```
def groups_by_role
    member_principals.find(:all, :include => [:principal, :roles]).inject({}) do |h, m|
      m.roles.each do |r|
        h[r] ||= []
        h[r] << m.principal
      end
      h
    end
  end
```

Controller:  projects_controller.rb

`@groups_by_role = @project.groups_by_role`

Views: members_index.html.rb

```
<% if @groups_by_role.any? %>
<div class="members box">
    <h3><%= l(:label_member_plural)%></h3>
    <p>
        <% @groups_by_role.keys.sort.each do |role| %>
        <%= h role %>: <%= @groups_by_role[role].sort.collect{|u| u}.join(", ").html_safe %>
        <br />
        <% end %>
    </p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I have a model which has a method group_by_role which finds all the roles and principal. Here principal defines users and groups which belong to a specific role. This method is a part of project.rb.

Later, I am defining the same method in the controller to a project and assigning that to an instance variable for it to available to the view i.e, @groups_by_role.

Finally, collecting and displaying the role for the particular user and group.

The output from the console for a particular @project look something like this: @groups_by_role

```
{#<Role id: 18, name: "Project Manager", permissions: [:add_project, :edit_project, :close_project], issues_visibility: "all">=>[#<User id: 11, login: "test1", firstname: "Test", lastname: "T", type: "User">], 

#<Role id: 26, name: "Readers", permissions: [:view_documents, :view_files], issues_visibility: "default">=>[#<Group id: 835, login: "", firstname: "", lastname: "AA", type: "Group">, #<User id: 107, login: "testab", firstname: "Tommy", lastname: "Ab", type: "User">, #<User id: 111, login: "testxyz", hashed_password: "", firstname: "test", lastname: "xyz", type: "User">]}
```

@groups_by_role.class = Hash

**Question:** Now I am getting the output with a role and with the respective User or Group. But I want to change the display here. If a hash contains only users without any group then i display only the user. Thus for this output `{#<Role id: 18, name: "Project Manager", permissions: [:add_project, :edit_project, :close_project], issues_visibility: "all">=>[#<User id: 11, login: "test1", firstname: "Test", lastname: "T", type: "User">],` 
As it has only user then I display the user. This works fine as it has only user but not group...

**But if there are both users and group in a hash then i display only the group name but not the user**. Currently It displays the users and groups like in this example:`#<Role id: 26, name: "Readers", permissions: [:view_documents, :view_files], issues_visibility: "default">=>[#<Group id: 835, login: "", firstname: "", lastname: "AA", *type: "Group"*>, #<User id: 107, login: "testab", firstname: "Tommy", lastname: "Ab", *type: "User"*>, #<User id: 111, login: "testxyz", hashed_password: "", firstname: "test", lastname: "xyz", type: "User">]}`

Is there any way to pass a condition inside the view or controller and check if a hash returns both users and group then only the group has to be displayed.
Can someone please help me in this. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I've understand you correctly.

Create a helper method (for controller) which will return a string like this:

```
def print_principals(principals)
  if principals.index {|p| p.is_a? Group }
    principals = principals.reject{|u| u.is_a? User }
  end
  # WARNING!!! You should apply html_safe only if you're sure that it 
  # is actually safe, i.e. not input by user. Otherwise consider escaping it.
  principals.sort.collect{|u| u}.join(", ").html_safe 
end
```

In your view: 
`<%= h role %>:  <%= print_principals @groups_by_role[role] %>`